# Can't compare strings/chars in insensitive cases (error - methods not found)

Tags: c++, string, char, string-comparison

I'm having problems with comparing two strings in case-insesitive way.
I've tried lots of methods(functions) like *strcasecmp, stricmp, strcmpi, etc*. I had imported the libraries where those functions belong but still it can't seem to detect them.

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <mem.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  char s1[100], s2[100];
  cin >> s1;
  cin >> s2;
  cout << strcasecmp(s1, s2) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

- 

```
ERROR: project.cpp|13|error: 'strcasecmp' was not declared in this scope
```

Does anybody have suggestions on how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: decide what langauge you want to write. Your code is not C, though it also doesnt look like C++

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, please don't tag both unless your program is actually using both languages.

Comment: Try `#include <strings.h>` instead of `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: `strcasecmp` is not in the C or C++ standard. It's defined by POSIX.1-2001 and 4.4BSD.

Comment: @MikeCAT
I've tried that as well, nothing seems to give me a chance to compare in case-insensitive way.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, my bad. I thought they do not differ that much.

Comment: @MarekR Okay? So how do I do it in C++? I'm quite new to this language. Because when I googled for the solution there were bunch of results like this.

Comment: The easiest choice is `boost::iequals`

Comment: Solved my problem with installing MinGW-W64 instead of MinGW32.

Comment: You don't need to add "(Solved)" to the title. Everyone can see when a question has an accepted answer or is marked as a duplicate.